# How can I use vmbuilder to install the dev ubuntu release?

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I'd like to try some packaging for oneric and vmbuilder seems like the easiest way to install it in kvm, but when I tell vmbuilder to install oneric it says it only knows through natty.

```
jrwren@delays:{4}~ $ sudo vmbuilder kvm ubuntu --suite oneric
2011-07-29 11:16:30,578 INFO    : Calling hook: preflight_check
2011-07-29 11:16:30,579 INFO    : Cleaning up
2011-07-29 11:16:30,579 ERROR   : Invalid suite: "oneric". Valid suites are: dapper gutsy hardy intrepid jaunty karmic lucid maverick natty
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/vmbuilder", line 24, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/VMBuilder/contrib/cli.py", line 216, in main
    distro.build_chroot()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/VMBuilder/distro.py", line 81, in build_chroot
    self.call_hooks('preflight_check')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/VMBuilder/distro.py", line 67, in call_hooks
    call_hooks(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/VMBuilder/util.py", line 165, in call_hooks
    getattr(context, func, log_no_such_method)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/VMBuilder/plugins/ubuntu/distro.py", line 100, in preflight_check
    raise VMBuilderUserError('Invalid suite: "%s". Valid suites are: %s' % (suite, ' '.join(self.suites)))
VMBuilder.exception.VMBuilderUserError: Invalid suite: "oneric". Valid suites are: dapper gutsy hardy intrepid jaunty karmic lucid maverick natty
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there's a tool that does this automatically called [testdrive](http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2010/03/ubuntu-prerelease-testing-made-easy-with-testdrive.ars). 
Testdrive is the right way to run the ubuntu dev release in kvm/qemu.

Command line instructions:

```
sudo apt-get install testdrive
testdrive
```

Then pick the right menu choice.

In my case I am on a headless server, so I get an error about SDL when testdrive starts KVM. I copy the KVM command and paste it and add -curses -vnc 127.0.0.1:0

Now I can VNC to my ubuntu dev VM.